# copy file content to a buffer using rdbuf failed

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to copy file content to a buffer.

```
std::ifstream fp(myFile, std::ios::binary)
fp.seekg(0, fp.end); // set cursor at the end
int length = fp.tellg(); // get data size
fp.seekg(0, fp.beg); // go back to buffer begin

char data[1000];
if(length<1000) {
    memcpy(data, fp.rdbuf(), length); // This crash

    std::stringstream contents;
    contents << fp.rdbuf();
    memcpy(data, contents->str().c_str(), length); // works fine
}
```

Copy using rdbuf directly crash, but copy on stringstream then in buffer works fine.

Does anybody has an explanation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the [`rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) function doesn't actually return the data, it returns a stream buffer instance. The input operator `<<` is overloaded to handle this object instance, but `memcpy` don't know what do do with it.

Answer (score 2):

`rdbuf()` does not return a buffer you can use memcpy on, it returns a `streambuf` object.